# to choose condition for if-statement

Tags: c, if-statement, struct

I want to make changes to an inventory balance. By simple logic if I input a number > 0 it should add and subtract if the number is < 0 subtract. So far it works fine.

Now to the issue. If the number that user types is less than inventory balance itself the program should set the value of inventory balance to 0.

For example if the invetory balance is 17 and we type number -18 it should be 0 and not -1.

This is my code so far.

```
printf("Increase or decrease by: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

if(n >= 0){
    a[i].inventory = a[i].inventory+n;
}else{
    a[i].inventory = a[i].inventory+n;   // +- = -
    if(n < a[i].inventory){
        a[i].inventory = a[i].inventory- a[i].inventory;
    }
```

I tried adding the last if-statement, but considering the "bad" logic of if condition, it does not work.
bad logic: if inventory is 17 and I want to subtract 2, it will always be less than a[i].inventory and it will jump over else and run the last if-statement.

Comment: I would rephrase the requirements to something like "If `n` is negative and its absolute value (i.e. the *negative* of the negative number) is larger than the inventory, set the inventory to zero; Else add `n` to the inventory". Then implement it in your code.

Comment: If inventory balance is 20 and I subtract 5 it works, but then when I subtract 12, it goes down to 0 instead of 3. Any idea why? absolute value of -12 is not greater than inventory balance so I do not get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are over-complicating a simple task.

```c
a[i].inventory += n; /* n can be negative too. */

if (a[i].inventory < 0)
    a[i].inventory = 0;
```

Comment: I don't think an accountant would approve of such an inventory algorithm. It should probably be `if(a[i].inventory + n < 0) { printf("you can't withdraw more items than what's in store!"); } else { a[i].inventory += n; }`

Comment: @Lundin Or you could communicate back to the client that they are receiving less than demanded. Or you could automatically submit a stock count correction when you discover there's more on the shelf than accounted. It depends on the use case.

Comment: Yes. This entire block should be within if clause: `if (!accountant) { ... }`